# Modal show and hide

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, view, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show/hide a modal in the view that has a fade class within my script section but its not showing.
Please, what's that I am doing wrong? the code is attached below.

The view:

```
<div class="modal modal-top fade" id="showModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="font-weight-bold">Add City of choice</span></h4>
                        <button id="btn" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">x</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <label class="form-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City" required name="name" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <label class="form-label">Rate</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Rate" required name="rate" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Min Order</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Min Order" name="minOrder" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <label class="switcher">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="switcher-input" name="allowFree" value="" />
                                <span class="switcher-indicator">
                                    <span class="switcher-yes"></span>
                                    <span class="switcher-no"></span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="switcher-label">Free Delivery</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button id="hideModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Submit</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("body").on("change", "#ddlStates", function () {
                    $("#hfStateName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
                });

                $("#submitBtn").click(function () {

                    var value = $("#selectedState").val();
                    $('#ListSubmit').append(value);

                });
            

                // Displaying the City details modal
                $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
                    $("#showModal").modal("show");

                // Close modal on button click
                    $("#hideModal").click(function () {
                    $("#showModal").modal("hide");
                });
        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`});` is needed at the end of your second `submitBtn` click function,but you'd better create only one click function for one button：

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("body").on("change", "#ddlStates", function () {
                    $("#hfStateName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
                });

                $("#submitBtn").click(function () {

                    var value = $("#selectedState").val();
                    $('#ListSubmit').append(value);
                    $("#showModal").modal("show");
                });
            
                // Close modal on button click
                    $("#hideModal").click(function () {
                    $("#showModal").modal("hide");
                });
        });
```

result:
[image]